# What is the difference between "neŭtra" and "neŭtrala"?

Tags: word-choice, meaning

What is the difference between *neŭtra* and *neŭtrala*? I learned that they both translate to *neutral* in English. Is there a nuanced difference between those two words?

Comment: It seems as if English just isn't specific enough in this instance. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are two different words.

From Vortaro:

Neŭtra 
*Tia, ke ĝi apartenas nek al unu nek al alia el du kategorioj.* 
That which belongs to neither of two categories.

Examples: Neither man or woman, acidic or alkaline, positive or negative (charge).

Neŭtrala 
*Ne partoprenanta, nek volanta partopreni en diskuto, konflikto, milito.* 
Not participating, nor wanting to participate in a discussion, conflict, war.

Examples: Neutral country, neutral language.

Answer (score 7):

According to JC Wells' dictionary, *neŭtra* is "neuter", ie something neither masculine nor feminine, mostly in grammar. I guess you could say *La veterinaro neŭtrigis la katon* for a non-grammar example. Something very different from "neutral"!

Only *neŭtrala* means "neutral".

Comment: I think *neŭtrigis* is a more common choice.